# Is Hankelability NP-hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I asked this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484864/an-algorithm-to-detect-permutations-of-hankel-matrices)  on April 7 and added a bounty which has now expired but no poly time solution has been found yet.

I am trying to write code to detect if a matrix is a permutation of a Hankel matrix.  Here is the spec.

**Input:** An n by n matrix M whose entries are 1 or 0.

**Output:** A permutation of the rows and columns of M so that M is a [Hankel matrix](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) if that is possible. A Hankel matrix has constant skew-diagonals (positive sloping diagonals).

When I say a permutation, I mean we can apply one permutation to the order of the rows and a possibly different one to the columns.

A very nice $O(n^2)$ time algorithm [is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704900/determine-if-some-row-permutation-of-a-matrix-is-toeplitz) for this problem if we only allow permutation of the order of rows.

Peter de Rivaz pointed out this [paper](http://www.mat.ucsb.edu/~g.legrady/academic/courses/15w259/d/re_orderableMatrix.pdf) as a possible route to proving NP-hardness but I haven't managed to get that to work.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe this problem is [GI-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#GI-complete_and_GI-hard_problems)?

Comment: Do you mean that the same permutation is applied to rows and columns? (my got feeling says this is in P, if a matrix is Hankelable with different diagonal values there aren't that many possibilities for the permutation.)

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks for the question. The permutation applied to the order of the columns can be different from the one applied to the order of the rows.

Comment: Do you mean apply first some permutation on the rows and then some permutation on the columns? or do you allow more permutations?

Comment: @IgorShinkar I mean first some permutation on the order of the rows and then a possibly different permutation on the order of the columns, then stop.

Comment: Cross-posted now to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204294/is-hankelability-np-hard